# Remover o focus do input quando ele esta com o attr readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte problema, tenho um *input* com o atributo `readonly`. Quando se clica nele ele é selecionado. Eu precisava impedir isso, pois tenho uma função utilizando o `onblu`r que só pode funcionar quando o *input* não está em `readonly`.

```html
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" onblur="alert('teste')">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode tratar isso com JavaScript,
segue uma solução pra você:

```js
function minhafuncao(teste){
  if(document.getElementById('idinput').readOnly==false){
    //seu comando
    alert(teste);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="idinput" readonly onblur="minhafuncao('teste')">
```

Comment: Esta solução me atendeu 100% obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar `disabled="true"`, e quando for remover o readonly também habilitar o input.

```html
<input type="text" disabled="true" readonly="readonly" onblur="alert('teste')">
```

Ou checar se está como readonly no blur com jQuery:

```js
$("#a").on("blur",function(){
  if ($(this).attr('readonly') == 'readonly'){
    console.log("Somente leitura");
  } else{
    console.log("Habilitado");  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Então Lucas, neste caso não posso usar disabled para evitar de não enviar o campo.

Comment: Você pode verificar se está como readonly na função, como sugeri na segunda opção.

Comment: Entendi, realmente uma solução, obrigado.